# How to resolve the Flink hadoop utils error?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

After building the app jar for flink when I submit the job I see error as below but the jar is available and added to sbt as well as the enable plugin list:

```
Submitting job...
/opt/flink/bin/flink run --jobmanager flink-archiver-kinesis2iceberg- 
jobmanager:8081 --class io.archiver.Job -- 
parallelism 2 --detached /opt/artifacts/sp-archive-scala-2.12.jar
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
org.apache.flink.runtime.util.HadoopUtils
    at io.archiver.Job$.main(Job.scala:54)
    at io.archiver.Job.main(Job.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What tool do you use for building the jar?

Comment: docker and buildkite I am using for the jar build and image as container

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop related dependencies are required， which can be used https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/flink/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber/2.8.3-10.0/flink-shaded-hadoop-2-uber-2.8.3-10.0.jar.
（must using uber package！don't one by one）

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).